# Split column into rows when the Delimiter is vertical bar ( | ) in R

Tags: r, delimiter, tidyr

```
#Input Table :-

Movie  Genre


Avatar Action|Sci-Fi


#Output Table Required <- 

Movie   Genre

Avatar        Action

Avatar         Sci-Fi

#Consider the name of the dataframe is input
```

I tried

```
output <-separate_rows(input, genre)
```

The resulted in :-

```
Avatar        Action

Avatar         Sci

Avatar    Fi
```

Which is not what is required

Comment: You can give a separator to `separate_rows`. If you look at the docs, it separates by punctuation marks by default, which includes `-`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `separate_rows(input, genre, sep='\\|')`

(`sep` is a regular expression so the `|` needs to be escaped with `\\`.)

Comment: Upvote but I'm closing as dupe.